# Create non clustered primary key with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate

Suppose I have following table:

```
 public class ResourcePossibleUm : EntityBase
    {
        public virtual bool IsMain { get; set; }
        public virtual double UmMass { get; set; }
        -------
    }
```

And mapping:

```
 public class ResourcePosibleUMMap : ClassMap<ResourcePossibleUm>
    {
        public ResourcePosibleUMMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();           
            Map(x => x.IsMain);
            Map(c => c.UmMass);
        }
    }
```

I am working with **sql server 2008**.
By default sql server 2008 will set my primary key (Id) like clustered index but I really don't want it . I want ["IsMain"] column to be clustered index.I want to set ["IsMain"] column like clustered index s using fluent Nhibernate but I can't figure out how to do this. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
public class CustomMsSql2008Dialect : MsSql2008Dialect
        {
            public override string PrimaryKeyString
            {
                get { return "primary key nonclustered"; }
            }           

        }
```

Now using CustomMsSql2008Dialect  like Dialect in configuration initialization I  will not have primary key like clustered index , id will be nonclustered index.

Comment: with this approach all PrimaryKeys will be non clustered, but only one should be

Comment: Yes I know it, this  is title of my question , so your down vote is unfounded.In order do down vote probably you should provide us with better solution and after this to down vote.